# What encoding I should choose for transcriptions?

Tags: android, iphone, ruby, fonts, transcription

My friends and I are developing an app for iphone and android. We need to work with word transcription. What encoding (or even special font) we should to choose to show correct word transcription in our applications?

**UPDATE (Dec 14, 2011):** I would like to provide more info. I try to read some transcriptions from Muller dictionary (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdxf/files/dicts-XDXF/sdict05/comn_sdict_axm05_mueller24.tar.bz2/download) and got problems with some characters.
I check dictionary file encoding with `enca`

```
~/mueller24 % enca dict.xdxf                                                           
Universal transformation format 8 bits; UTF-8
```

One of problematic word is a 'painter'. When I open dictionary file in emacs I see:

[image]

With data works our script written in ruby. It parses this transcription from dictionary and store in database. And after that it took this transcription from database and write it as json to files (utf-8). If I open this file in text editor I see it as this string `\u0445peInt\u255a`

And if I parse it in my app and show on screen it seems like that:

[image]

Where is the mistake? I suppose that problem in parsing dictionary file. Than how to parse it correctly?

Comment: How are word transcriptions different from other text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 (compact, and backwards-compatible)

Comment: That file is explicitly UTF-8 (in the XML header). From your screen shot, the data for painter looks wrong, I'd expect it to match painting (ˈpeɪntə). I think you have a combining diacritic in there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. We try to open this file in StarDict application and transcriptions for this words are good there. Than I just copied transcription strings from there to my files with json, parse it in iphone app and it shows correctly. I will go deeper into our parsing script in ruby. Thanks for response!

Comment: If this were my project, I would fix the data and not the parsing. I'm rusty with IPA but it looks like the first 3 "characters" of painter are just wrong. (I suppose you could write code to check for bad data, if another program is returning just ˈpeɪntə then it must be doing that.) It was several years ago, but I recall getting one or two bad entries in a commercial dictionary (which was also provided in XML).

Comment: we have already checked dictionary file with StarDict programm (dictionary programm) and it shows our 'bad' words good. That's why I suppose that problem in our parsing script.

Comment: I just tried downloading StarDict. Doesn't run at all on Mac OS X any more (just box characters). I couldn't figure out how to load a dictionary on Windows. Given how awful the UI is, I wouldn't trust much about it. The data looks bad to my eyes, there are extra characters before the true IPA pronunciation. I suspect a bug in how StarDict displays Unicode combining marks before I suspect your parsing.